# Populate Django Drop Down List from another Drop Down List - Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django, forms

I have a Django + Python website, where user can request a access to a database. So in this form the user has these options.

Environment: This is a drop down list with two values: Development and Production
Permission: This is another drop down list with two values: Read and Read/Write

What I am trying to achieve is:

```
If Environment == Development
   AddToPermissionDropDownList: Database Owner
else
 Permission
```

So, as you can see, I want to populate one drop down list based in the selected value of another drop down.

I know that I need to use JavaScript to achieve that, but I am stuck on how to do it.

This is what I have been able to do so far.

models.py

```
class NewAccessRequest(models.Model):
permission_needed = models.CharField(max_length=25,verbose_name='Permissions')
```

forms.py

```
class AccessRequestForm(ModelForm):
environment= forms.ChoiceField(choices=ENVIRONMENT_CHOICES,label="",initial='',widget=forms.Select(attrs={'id':'environment','onchange':'changePermissions()'}), required=True)
permission_needed = forms.ChoiceField(initial='',widget=forms.Select(), required=True)
```

access.html

```
<form>
{% csrf_token %}
   <label for="{{ form.environment.id_for_label }}">Environment:</label>
    <p>{{form.environment}}</p>
<script>
function changePermissions() {
var EnvChosen = document.getElementById("environment").value;
if (EnvChosen == "DEV") {
document.getElementById("id_business_reason").value = "This is a test"

        }
    }
    </script>
</form>
```

Comment: Since you are working with a small number of values, you could just have two arrays in JavaScript, and write some code to (re) populate the second menu depending on the value of the first. You'll need to trap the change event on the first menu. You can do this in raw JS, or some people prefer to use a library like jQuery. Break the problem down into pieces - can you get a change event working first?

Comment: I am. From the forms.py I am sending the following

widget=forms.Select(attrs='id':'environment','onchange':'changePermissions()'})

I did some very basic testing, like when changing the environment value, I just set a testing a another field.

Comment: Great, would you put that code into your question? It's hard to know how far you've got (or how much JS you know) without a bit more detail.

Comment: I've added now. My skillset with javascript and related is very basic.

Answer (score 0):

Since it needs to be populated from the options from back end . 
you can call a ajax method to get the data from back end on the change event of dropdown-1  , then you have to populate dropdown-2 with  data got from the response of the ajax , also you have to pass the value from dropdown-1 with the request. you can either use a get or post request. if it is post request you also need to pass csrf token

Comment: I thought about suggesting an AJAX approach, but given the OP is not at an advanced level, and they only have two menus, each with two values, I wonder if just keeping the elements in an in-page JS array would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have been able to do so far. The only problem that I am seeing is.

1) In the environment drop down list I select: DEV
   1.1) DB OWNER gets added
2) Now change the environment drop down list to: PROD
   2.1) DB READER gets added
3) Now change the environment drop down list to: DEV
   3.1) DB OWNER gets added again.

I know that I need somehow to cleanup the values in the drop down list, I just don't know yet on where and what code to do.

```
<script>
function changePermissions() {
   var EnvChosen = document.getElementById("environment").value;
   var selectList = document.getElementById("id_permission_needed")

   if (EnvChosen == "DEV") {
        var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
        var txt = document.createTextNode("DB OWNER");
        option.appendChild(txt);
        selectList.insertBefore(option, selectList.lastChild);
       }
   if (EnvChosen == "PROD") {
         var option = document.createElement("OPTION");
         var txt = document.createTextNode("DB READER");
         option.appendChild(txt);
         selectList.insertBefore(option, selectList.lastChild);
              }
          }
    </script>
```